# Render react component from javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render react component on javascript so i tried so many thing and nothing positive.Why that doesn't render  ? :

```
this.qwe = document.createElement('react-component');
this.qwe.setAttribute("name","qweqwe");

tr.appendChild(this.qwe);
this.tBody.appendChild(tr);
```

Comment: Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: That's not how React works. Only way you can get a React Component's HTML is by using `ReactDOM.render`. React Components are not DOM elements but JavaScript functions/classes. Someone needs to create a new instance and call it's `render` method. That someone is you, using `ReactDOM.render`.

Comment: I tried and that too but its say ReactDOM not defined

Comment: That's because you probably did not include React in your page. Try the getting started tutorial in the official documentation pages.

Comment: i tried to include but its say unexptected token import

Comment: That's because you didn't transpile your JavaScript using Babel. It's all documented on the getting started page.

Comment: @FreakProgrammer take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/reactjs/797/getting-started-with-react#t=201610270802428874351). Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes thank toy its help me a lot but i cant just import babel and that kind of thinks i need to include ReactDom.. when you have a realy realy big project and you need to do only one component its stupid to import babel cuz may crash something else..There is some other way to do that what i want ?

Comment: @FreakProgrammer, don't think so, no. React is a library and needs compiling. It doesn't run out of the box like plain javascript does. You have to compile React code.